# How to Redirect specific category product pages to cart page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

i want to redirect users when they click single page product directly to cart without going to product description page for only one category products.

i used this code:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'ts_redirect_product_pages', 99 );

function ts_redirect_product_pages() {
     
    if ( is_product() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/cart/')); 
        exit;
    } 
}
```

it's redirecting to the cart page but all the other product categories also redirecting i only want one product category to be redirected, please guide me how to do this

Comment: Hi, it is redirecting to the cart page(no products in the cart), can you please tell me the single page product we are clicking should be added into the cart page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `template_redirect` hook. To target specific product category(ies), you can use WordPress `has_term()` conditional function. For cart url, is better to use WooCommerce function `wc_get_cart_url()`...

So in the code below define your product category(ies) term(s) name(s), slug(s) or Id(s):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ts_redirect_product_pages' );

function ts_redirect_product_pages() {
    $categories = array('my-category-1', 'my-category-2');

    if ( is_product() && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme *(or active theme)*. It should work.

Comment: Hi, it is redirecting to the cart page(no products in the cart), can you please tell me the single page product we are clicking should be added into the cart page.